# Need help in troubleshooting association in Rails !

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and and I'm on the urge of learning Associations.
I'm using Rails version 3.
I have a user model and post model.My need is as below:-

*Models*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :post  
end  

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user  
  validates_associated :user  
end
```

*Schema*

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20101016171256) do  
  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|  
    t.integer  "sell_or_buy"  
    t.string   "title"  
    t.text     "body"  
    t.integer  "user_id"  <<<<<<< I thought this will help to associate to user model.  
    t.datetime "created_at"  
    t.datetime "updated_at"  
  end  

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|  
    t.string   "name"  
    t.string   "email"  
    t.string   "password"  
    t.integer  "rank"  
    t.datetime "created_at"  
    t.datetime "updated_at"  
  end  
end
```

I thought keeping a `user_id` field and the `belongs_to` association will do my job, but
when i tried to display all the posts belonging to a user as follows:

```
<%= @user.posts %>
```

in my show.html.erb file. But I get only the following display:-

```
Name:  saran  

Email: saran.saran007@gmail.com  

Password: abcd  

Rank:    
Edit | Back  
Posts  
#<Post:0xb69f47f8>#<Post:0xb69f3024>
```

I want to display the associated posts "title" and "body" in a readable format.

Also I'm able to create a post with a user_id in which no user exists!. The   `validates_associated :user` is also not working, Please help me out.

Comment: This is just a guess, I will try to take a look at this later, but on the face of it this may be a pluralization issue -- could you try 'has_many :posts', maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the posts as expected in your view... So I'm not sure I understand that part of your question. As to the other part, `validates_associated` just ensures that the attached object is valid itself, and not if it exists at all. For that you want `validates_presence_of`. [See the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated).

Comment: I want to display the complete Post in a readable format.I want to display its title and body.

Comment: Well, your question is about the association being broken... Obviously to output the post in readable format you just use the properties in your model and generate markup: `<% @user.posts.each do |post| -%><h2><%= post.title %></h2><p><%= post.body %></p><% end -%>` and so on just like you did with the user to get their name on the page.

Answer (score 3):

Its

```
class User
  has_many :posts
end
```

Not

```
has_many :post
```

Edit and Update your results.

Comment: Very true... but, odd how his code with `has_many :post` correctly finds and outputs Post objects though, eh?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following partial for my purpose and it works well :).
Thanks for all your inputs.

```
<% for post in @user.posts do %>    
   <h3> <%= post.title %> </h3>   
   <%= post.body %>   
<% end %>
```